# How can I get browser console on Rails 6 System test capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am using Rails 6 System test to test javascript on Browser. My work is get all browser console log on browser and print on rails console. However, I can't find any suggestion from Google.

Comment: What driver and browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome and when I run $ rails test:system, browser is open and run normally, but chrome console log can't send to my rails console

Comment: I have printed browser console logs to rails console by inserting command to my test case: ```page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)```. Thanks for your help.